# gzip all files to root folder in .tar?

Tags: tar, gzip

The command below will create a .tar.gz with another archive in it which contains the actual files.

Is it possible to prevent the additional archive from being created and put all files directly inside the .tar.gz root folder?

> GZIP=-9 tar -czf temp.tar.gz *.txt

Comment: You could have an uncompressed `.tar` file, but I'm not sure that is what you intend. Gzip, bzip, etc. do not combine several files into one, that's what `tar` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a few things here

1 - 2 archives - a .gz (or .bz2) file, that contains a .tar file.

This is done because `gzip`/`bzip2` only work on a single file.  Once a file is compressed, the uncompressed version is removed.  Uncompress it, and when done the compressed version is removed.

The `tar` command, (historically) didn't do compression on its own.  But thanks to the open source goodness that they all 3 are, the shared libraries and some code let `tar` work with compression on the fly.

Perhaps the old Slackware/DOS 8.3 convention filename extension would help you think of it better - `.tgz` or `.tbz`